# Unknown Abbreviations in abstract of probate

Tags: will, probate-records, abbreviations

I have found a number of abstracts from another researcher and do not know exactly what they mean. The following is a typical one:

> Eliab Cooper
>   b. 1767, Charles County, MD
>   Father:  Jesse Cooper
>   Mother:  Esther Ratcliff
>   Esther Cooper 5.150 D CH £58.4.2 Feb 17 1769
>   Sureties: Thomas Price, Richard Price.
>   Distribution to (equally): Karen Hepuch Cooper, Zeporah Cooper, Eliab Cooper.
>   Administrator: Joseph Ratliff.

In another entry there is this: "Esther Cooper 61.53 A CH £22.15.0 £32.2.4 Feb 17 1769"

I understand that these are distributions of assets from a will. However, I do not understand the abbreviations "5.150 D CH" or "61.53 A CH " within the context of the entries.

Comment: I've edited your title and question because this is not a citation. It is an extract or abstract of the information contained in whatever the original document might have been.  A typical citation would point back to the original document and the archive or repository where it could be found.

Comment: For reference, one location these quoted entries occur is [here](http://www.colonial-settlers-md-va.us/getperson.php?personID=I053166&tree=tree1) on the colonial-settlers-md-va.us website.

Comment: @JanMurphy I thank you for edit and suggestions, It is much appreciated.

Comment: @AndyW Many thanks for the website suggestion.

Comment: Paul, feel free to make further edits as needed. I do try to preserve the meaning as much as possible.  Where did you find the information?

Answer (score 6):

"CH" refers to CHarles County, Maryland.

"A" (meaning "account") can be found in these documents: "Abstracts of the Administration Accounts of the Prerogative Court; (multiple editions, called "Libers," see "Sources" below); V. L. Skinner, Jr.

"D" stands for "deed."

The numbers (5.150, for instance) come from the "Charles County Maryland Probate Records, Inventories, Book 1717-1735" or "Charles Co, Maryland: Probate Records and Inventories Part I 1673 - 1753," depending on date. The first number is supposed to be "the page or folio number for the beginning of the document" (as described in the "Maryland Genealogical Society Bulletin; Winter 1984 Vol 25 No 2;"). The Maryland Genealogical Society Bulletin itself is sold out but the article on Charles County records is theoretically orderable [here](http://www.mdgensoc.org/upload/files/allowIndex/MdGS_Bulletin_ToC.pdf).

The listed date is the date that the "Inventory" (assets in question) was dealt with.

Sources:

- [Abstracts of the Administration Accounts of the Prerogative Court, multiple editions.](http://txsaghs.org/libraryRecords.php?page=1&nr=50&le=f1_c70&scl=bta)
- [Information on Charles County abbreviations.](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=40752987)
- "Maryland Genealogical Society Bulletin; Winter 1984 Vol 25 No 2" as cited in multiple genealogical webpages.

Comment: You have been most helpful. I have learned a lot and I appreciate your detailed explanation.